# Performance issue with TOP (1) on a nullable column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance, t-sql

I need help to identify the reason for a performance issue.

Actually following query sits in a scalar-valued-function but that is not the reason for the issue since it needs the same time as query:

```
SELECT TOP (1) dd.gsp_part_price 
FROM  tabdata 
       INNER JOIN locsl 
               ON tabdata.fisl = locsl.idsl 
       INNER JOIN locgsp 
               ON locsl.figsp = locgsp.idgsp 
       INNER JOIN tabdatadetail dd
               ON dd.fidata = tabdata.iddata 
       INNER JOIN tabsparepart sp 
               ON dd.fisparepart = sp.idsparepart 
WHERE  sp.sparepartname = '1270-3132' 
       AND dd.gsp_part_price IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY Claim_Submitted_Date DESC
```

This query returns the price immediately for most spareparts but some parts need several minutes to return `NULL`. So this query returns 940 rows immediately for the same part as above where every `gsp_part_price` is `NULL` which is the reason for the `NULL` above:

```
SELECT dd.*, sp.* 
FROM tabdatadetail dd 
INNER JOIN tabsparepart sp 
    on dd.fisparepart=sp.idsparepart
WHERE sp.sparepartname='1270-3132'
```

Why does the first query needs 3 minutes to return `NULL` whereas the query below returns immediately the 940 rows? I must admit that i've still problems to interpret execution plans.

Note that the first query also returns immediately if i remove the `IS NOT NULL CHECK`:

```
dd.gsp_part_price IS NOT NULL
```

All involved tables are linked via foreign-keys, i have tried to add an index on  `gsp_part_price` which had no effect.

Here's the query execution plan:

[image: query execution plan]

**Edit**: Here are the stats on the PK and FK (to parent table `tabData`) indexes:

```
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS('dbo.tabDataDetail','PK_tabDataDetail') WITH STAT_HEADER;
PK_tabDataDetail    Nov  6 2013 10:04AM 64327191    387089  183 1   8   NO 

DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS('dbo.tabDataDetail','IX_fiData') WITH STAT_HEADER;
IX_fiData   Nov  6 2013 10:04AM 64327191    378150  198 0,2441889   4   NO 

DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS('dbo.tabDataDetail','IX_GspPartPrice') WITH STAT_HEADER;
IX_GspPartPrice Dez  3 2013 12:17PM 64788799    64788799    200 0,0002433512    7,065503    NO
```

The last index was added just now as mentioned above. So the actual rows are `64788799`, why the great difference between the estimated and actual rows, also , why is there a difference between the query-plan's actual rows and the "real" actual rows?

Here's the complete plan: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=86912774678831839436

**Edit**: from the comment of Mikael Eriksson:

> I think your `top(1)` and `order by` is to blame here. The index
>   scan is using the index on `Claim_Submitted_Date` to find the first
>   occurrence of a value as fast as possible. SQL Server thinks that you
>   will find such value after scanning 3000 rows. Perhaps that estimate
>   makes sense if you have 5000 rows in `tabSparePart` and you only want
>   one. The thing is that if there are no rows found or you have a spare
>   part that is just recently submitted, SQL Server will have to scan the
>   entire index before it figures out that there is no rows to be found.

Although i still don't understand why, it seems that this is true. If i remove the `TOP 1` or change it to say `TOP 1000` the result comes immediately. Does anybody have an  idea what i can do? Because, if multiple rows are returned i just need the last price submitted.

Comment: For tabdatadetail you have estimated rows 24.5k, actual rows 49.6 million? Can you post the plan XML, table definitions (including indexes) and stats on table sizes?

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith: I have added the stats and the actual plan.

Comment: Looks to me like `tabData` is where the bad estimate is coming from. Estimated number of rows is 2,298 rows and the actual number of rows is 15,677,028 rows. You could try to update statistics for `tabData`.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: I have used `EXEC sp_updatestats`  to update them but now the query runs 10 minutes without getting finished. Why is there a difference between 2,298  and 15,677,028 rows at all? I have updated statistics in november and the actual row-count was already above 15Million.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: The query plan's estimated rows changed from 2,298 to 2337 after i've updated the statistics. Whats going on?

Comment: I think your `top(1)` and `order by` is to blame here. The index scan is using the index on `Claim_Submitted_Date` to find the first occurrence of a value as fast as possible. SQL Server thinks that you will find such value after scanning 3000 rows. Perhaps that estimate makes sense if you have 5000 rows in `tabSparePart` and you only want one. The thing is that if there are no rows found or you have a spare part that is just recently submitted, SQL Server will have to scan the entire index before it figures out that there is no rows to be found.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: There are actually more than 14k rows in `tabSparePart`. There are 900 rows in `tabDataDetail` which link this sparepart but none that has a `gsp_part_price`  that is `NOT NULL` (which i'm searching). Why does it has to scan the whole table if a part was recently submitted since I'm ordering descending? What can i do? I'm open for any suggestions even if you're just guessing because i'm at my wits' end.

Comment: Ah, did not notice the `desc`. The same still applies but the other way around. No rows found as in when you are using  `sp.sparepartname = '1270-3132'` or submitted a long time ago.

Comment: I still don't understand why the `TOP 1` with `ORDER BY Claim_Submitted_Date DESC` is to blame. If i just select from `tabDataDetail` and `tabSparePart` the result comes immediately. But as soon as i include the parent table `tabData` with the order i have a problem. Now i have even tried to add an `Claim_Submitted_Date DESC` index but the result is the same. Why does SQL-Sever need to scan the entire index if the `tabDataDetail` result already yields `Null`?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: Although i still don't understandthe _why_, it seems that you're right. The _"top(1) and order by is to blame here"_. If i remove the `TOP 1` the result comes immediately. Do you have an idea what i can do? Because, if multiple rows are returned i just need the last price submitted.

Comment: If you get a good plan for `top(1000)` you can trick the optimizer with `declare @TOP int; set @TOP = 1; select top(@TOP) <-your query goes here-> option (optimize for (@TOP = 1000))`.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: Thanks for your valuable input. I have never used the `OPTIMIZE FOR Hint`. Maybe you want to add it as answer so that i can accept it. But i have a problem to include it in the actual function since i'm using an `If-Else` there to assign the price to a variable that i return. Where do i need to add the hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query takes a lot of time because it finds no rows.

The plan first is setup top pick one row from `tabSparePart` where `sparepartname = '1270-3132'`. It then moves along to the index scan of tabData. For each row fetched from `tabData` there is a clustered index seek in `locSL` followed by a clustered index seek in `tabDataDetail` which also checks for not null on `gsp_part_price` and finally returns the values of `fiSparePart` and `GSP_Part_Price`. `fiSparePart` is then compared against the `idSparePart` returned from the Index Seek in `tabSparePart`. If they are the same the query immediately terminates and return the `gsp_part_price`. If they are not the same the index scan in `tabData` moves to the next record and all the checks are executed again. That keeps happening until there is a row returned or all rows in `tabData` have been processed.

As it turns out you get a totally different query plan when you do top(1000).

You can use the `optimize for` hint to make SQL Server think you actually want 1000 rows when you only need one.

Your scalar valued function would then look something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FunctionName]()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @TOP INT
  DECLARE @RET INT

  SET @TOP = 1

  SELECT TOP (@TOP) @RET = dd.gsp_part_price 
  FROM  tabdata 
          INNER JOIN locsl 
                  ON tabdata.fisl = locsl.idsl 
          INNER JOIN locgsp 
                  ON locsl.figsp = locgsp.idgsp 
          INNER JOIN tabdatadetail dd
                  ON dd.fidata = tabdata.iddata 
          INNER JOIN tabsparepart sp 
                  ON dd.fisparepart = sp.idsparepart 
  WHERE  sp.sparepartname = '1270-3132' 
          AND dd.gsp_part_price IS NOT NULL 
  ORDER BY Claim_Submitted_Date DESC 
  OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR(@TOP = 1000))

  RETURN @RET

END
```

Comment: To add to this a bit, SQL Server has a deliberate optimization for top 1 through top 100 that uses a memory structure and doesn't sort the entire dataset. It goes wrong sometimes because it prioritizes which index it starts from to try and get the answer quicker. One path likes the order by index over one of the join indexes and sends SQL down a slow, slow path.  See this article for more: https://sqlkiwi.blogspot.com/2010/08/sorting-row-goals-and-the-top-100-problem.html